# GeoServer - compute from native bounds does not work correctly

Tags: geoserver, layers, extents

I am currently working on the topic GeoServer, so I am very new. 
For some layers it is not possible to calculate the BBox via the button "compute from native bounds". 
What can be the problem? 
What is the best way to troubleshoot?

[image: geoserver compute from native bounds]

Comment: your layer has no native bounds - it is probably empty, thus GeoServer can not calculate the projected bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right. The layer was actually accidentally empty.